# Multiple columns inserted in database

Tags: http, angular

I wrote some code in TypeScript for Angular 2. When I click on submit button, the data is appending to the database but the values that appears in the database is wrong

At one click, my database has 4 rows inserted with 1 row valid data and other 3 with null values.

This is my component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Component({
    templateUrl: './components/profile/profile.html'
})

export class Profile {
    http: Http;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }
    postResponse = new Person();

    onSubmit(form){
        //this.form = form;
        console.log(form);
        var headers = new Headers();
        //  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

        this.http.post('http://localhost/fin/index.php/profile/addprofile', JSON.stringify(form),{headers:headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
    }
}
class Person {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
}
```

My template

```
    <h3 class= "head">MY PROFILE</h3>

 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" #myForm="ngForm" >


  <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-lg-6" >
<div class="formHeading get">First Name</div>
<input type="text" id="firstName" class = "col-sm-7" ngControl="firstname"> 
 </div>
```

```
  <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-lg-6" >
    <div class="formHeading get" >Last Name</div>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" class = "col-sm-7" ngControl="lastname">
```

```
 <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-lg-6" >
   <div class="formHeading get">Email</div>
<input type="text" id="zip" class = "col-sm-7"  ngControl="email">
```

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-lg-6" >
<div class="formHeading get">Profile Name</div>
<input type="text" id="profileName" class = " col-sm-7"    ngControl="profilename">
```

```
  <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-lg-6" >
<div class="formHeading get">Contact Number</div>
<input type="text" id="firstName" class = " col-sm-7" ngControl="phone">
```

Save

I am not sure where the error is about and sometimes I see the correct data in the database and sometimes not. Can anyone find the error?

Comment: You probably have an issue on server side

Comment: i dont think so since i checked inserting from postman it worked fine.

Comment: does my code is correct?

Comment: Can you show us your form template?

Comment: ya rinukkusu,i posted ny templatae